# code C# use the Google OAuth to sign Google Acount

Tags: api, google-oauth

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.Apis.Blogger.v3;
using Google.Apis.Blogger.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Util;

namespace BloggerTest
{
 class Program
 {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   string apiKey= "{API-KEY}";
   string blogUrl= "{BLOG-URL}";

   string clientID = "{CLIENT_ID}";
   string clientSec = "{CLIENT_SECRET}";

   NativeApplicationClient provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description)
   {
    ClientIdentifier = clientID,
    ClientSecret = clientSec
   };

   OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient> auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, getAuth);

   BloggerService blogService = new BloggerService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
   {
    Authenticator = auth,
    ApplicationName = "BloggerTest"
   });

   BlogsResource.GetByUrlRequest getReq = blogService.Blogs.GetByUrl(blogUrl);
   getReq.Key = apiKey;
   Blog blog = getReq.Execute();
   Console.WriteLine(blog.Id);

   Console.ReadKey();

  }

  private static IAuthorizationState getAuth(NativeApplicationClient arg)
  {
   IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { BloggerService.Scopes.Blogger.GetStringValue() })
    {
     Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl)
    };
   Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);
   Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter auth code:");
   string authCode = Console.ReadLine();
   return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
  }
 }
}
```

And it have 2 error:

1. 'Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer' does not contain a definition for 'Authenticator'
2. 'Google.Apis.Blogger.v3.BloggerService' does not contain a definition for 'Scopes'

Can you help me fix. Thank you very much!

I get code from: http://garyngzhongbo.blogspot.com/2013/10/bloggerc-blogger-api-v3-6oauth-20.html

Comment: Were you ever able to fix it?  I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common problems faced by beginners when the implement Google APIs. These are both due to the API libraries being unstable, and changing from one release to the next.

1. When the API changes, the sample apps don't. So developers try to use out of date code with the latest API.
2. Links to old versions of the API libraries are not purged. So developers can find themselves downloading old libraries.

So 1 and 2 are kinda the opposite, but both occur. Problem 1 is the more common.

So in this case, check that you have downloaded the very latest versions of the API library, and check if the missing definitions have in fact been withdrawn, in which case you'll need to find a more up to date example.